# Consolidation of Nested For Loops

Tags: loops, for-loop

I am trying to write something that will compares a large list and if their are string matches then it copies that string to another list. So I want to make this as generic as possible meaning that the number of sheets in the file will be unknown and the number of values in each sheet will be ~800. Here is what I have so far. It runs and does what I want but I noticed it creates double entries of parts sometimes and it causes excel to become unresponsive. Making the loop smaller eliminates the double entries but this is not desired. Any help consolidating this would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False





Worksheets("Parts in common").Range("A12:AH1000").ClearContents
x = 2
w = 2

For Each sheet In Worksheets

If sheet.Name <> TextBox1.Text And sheet.Name <> "Parts in common" Then

w = 2

For y = 2 To 800
For i = 2 To 800


If sheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = Worksheets(TextBox1.Text).Cells(y, 2).Value Then
Worksheets("").Cells(w + 10, x).Value = sheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
Worksheets("").Cells(w + 10, x + 1).Value = sheet.Cells(i, 3).Value
Worksheets("").Cells(w + 10, x + 2).Value = sheet.Cells(i, 16).Value

w = w + 1




End If

Next i

Next y

End If

x = x + 3

Next sheet

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```